# Kafka producer Java api with zookeeper integration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

With Kafka Nodejs client (nodejs is kafka producer), we could find kafka-node with zookeeper integration. Is there similar package for Java as Kafka producer with integration of zookeeper. The purpose is that Java could talk to zookeeper only and let zookeeper to find kafka brokers so that even one broker is down, zookeeper would advice producer client to talk with the newly selected primary broker.

Comment: Interesting question! How do you handle zookeeper server failures?

Comment: there could be a couple of zookeepers, client api shall handle zookeeper failure also.